# Am I including font using PACK URI correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I want to include my fonts into application through styles. (Resource Dicitionaries) Seems like every font looks same.

I tried include these fonts using pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#font-name

Unfortunately that did not resolved my problem at all.

**Fonts.xaml**

```xml
<FontFamily x:Key="LatoThin">pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#Lato Thin</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="LatoRegular">pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#Lato Regular</FontFamily>
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>   
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Fonts.xaml" />  
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

I expect every font looks like it should instead I get default font.

Comment: Additional information: I found out that it work normally with WPF .Net Standard but doesn't work in .Net Core 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer.

I found out that it works with this code.

```
<FontFamily x:Key="LatoThin">Fonts/Lato-Thin.ttf #Lato Thin</FontFamily>
```